# Cordova Crosswalk + Framework7: Pixel errors

Tags: crosswalk-runtime, html-framework-7

I'm developing a HTML app with the Crosswalk WebView on Cordova. I'm using Framework7 for my UI.

Now I'm having the following problem: If I switch the page, my whole site looks destroyed. It seems like a graphical error. If I remove Crosswalk from Cordova, the app works finde on normal WebView. I'm using Android 4.4 (Galaxy Note 2).

Here is a image how it looks like:
https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/secure/attachment/12600/IMG_0484.JPG

I've tried to disable GPU rasterization, but that didn't work. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can i reproduce this with any of the Framework7 sample apps?

Comment: @Bale Solutions was to upgrade to the newest Crosswalk version. I'm using Meteor for development and they've used an old integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to newest Crosswalk version, works fine.